# Como exportar configurações de um tema Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, temas

Tenho um site WordPress e preciso migrar para outro servidor. Consegui exportar o conteúdo e importar no novo ambiente. Entretanto, o tema usado foi modificado bastante. Foram muitas configurações feitas. Existe uma forma de salvar todas as configurações e importar no novo ambiente?

**EDIT**
PS: Eu tenho acesso ao banco de dados.
PS2: O tema em questão é o Hueman.
PS3: Não encontrei nenhum dado no banco relacionado ao tema.

Comment: Você tem acesso direto ao banco de dados?

Comment: Tenho sim @RicardoMoraleida, mas não tem nada lá referente a este tema. Pelo menos eu não encontrei.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que existe! Vou te dar a solução passo a passo de um exemplo...

1. Exporte sua base de dados no MySQL através do phpmyadmin ou pelo terminal. Para isso, vá em sua base de dados principal, e selecione a que você gostaria de exportar. Se o seu phpmyadmin estiver em portugês, vá até a aba Exportar. Exporte ela para o tipo *.sql mesmo!
2. Agora, vamos fazer o download da sua plataforma wordpress. Para isso, é importante que a seu servidor suporte compactação de arquivos para não perder nenhum durante o download. Compacte seus arquivos no formato *.zip.
3. Depois de baixar os arquivos. Importe seu arquivo em seu servidor novo, use o phpmyadmin e vá na aba Importar. O tipo é *.sql.
4. Agora, importe seu arquivo *.zip para o servidor novo. Descompacte ele dentro do *www* ou *public_html*.
5. Em modo offline, vá até a raiz do diretório do wordpress, e vamos manipular o arquivo *wp-config.php*. Nesse arquivo você vai alterar as configurações do seu novo banco de dados. Depois salve o arquivo, e substitua o arquivo em seu novo servidor.
6. Agora, para terminar, você pode alterar o endereço do seu servidor na tabela *wp_option* (Geralmente fica aqui). Se o seu domínio estiver local, no endereço vai estar assim: http://localhost ... altere para o seu domínio.

Obs.: Servidores pagos possuem "Gerenciador de arquivos" no CPANEL. Nele, você pode compactar e descompactar arquivos zip.

Espero ter contribuido!